# Column level compression specification

Tags: parquet

In parquet-mr, currently we can specify a compression which by default is applied to all the columns. In future, when support to specify compression specific to individual columns is supported, will the current support of "default compression" be still supported or will it be deprecated?

Thanks,
Ravi C

Answer (score 0):

DefaultCodec just maps to a predefined other compression algorithm

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/DefaultCodec.html#line.68

It currently maps to ZLib compression.

DefaultCodec will still be around, but its mapping may change in the future, I guess for example, to SnappyCodec..